# Creating a Post with the Medium API

Tags: php, curl, medium.com-publishing-api

How can I create a post with the Medium API? I've followed the [documentation](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs#33-posts) and my code seems correct, but not getting a response:

```
$token = '2baemytoken6234324';

$post = [
    'title' => 'teseee',
    'contentFormat' => 'html',
    'content' => 'eeee',
];

$ch = curl_init('https://api.medium.com/v1/users/132434fafasfasf3434/posts');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Accept: application/json',
   'Accept-Charset: utf-8',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
   ));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: If you add `var_dump($info);` before the line `curl_close($ch);` , what do you see ?

Comment: shows me a long array of the request info

Comment: If you set publishStatus to be "public" in your $post, what happens ?

Comment: still no response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `json_encode($post)`. The below script is working for me:

```
<?php

$authorId = '179b6b8a8efc9f4f58ad5475c6b6004af5b15';
$token = '2e6746584d02a677d7575bc7eb89c8789f724cfd';

$curl = curl_init();

$post = [
    "title"         => "Medium API - Testing",
    "contentFormat" => "html",
    "content"       => "<h1>This post is created with Medium API</h1><p>Jai Jinnedra</p>",
    "tags"          => [ "api", "medium", "stakeoverflow" ],
    "publishStatus" => "public",
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.medium.com/v1/users/'.$authorId.'/posts',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: this worked! thank you! seems to be something slightly different with encoding, etc